# I am getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dna.txt' on Pycharm? Where do I put file to read?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to open 2 text files on PyCharm but it says file not found. Where do I put the files so they can be found?

I tried moving the files to the folder where all my PyCharm projects are kept but it didn't work.

```
dna = open('dna.txt', 'r')
dna.close()

dna_results = open("dnaresults.txt", "w")
dna_results.close()
```

Expected: I don't know honestly, for the text file to open on PyCharm so I can read it?

Actual: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dna.txt'

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the file, check my answer below!

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the file, Please check my answer below! @Jonathan :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the full path of the file in order to open it, for e.g. if the file is located at `/home/john/dna.txt`, you need to do.

```
dna = open('/home/john/dna.txt', 'r')
dna.close()
```

You can put your file anywhere you want, but you always need to pass the full path of the file in order to access it, otherwise the python interpreter doesn't know where to find it.

As an additional tidbit, if the `dna.txt` is located in the same folder as where the script is located, `dna = open('dna.txt', 'r')` will work